# Regular Expression to allow only one pattern among the two

Tags: java, regex

I have a text field which will contain strings "Yes" or "No"

I need a regular expression which will allow only one of those strings. ie The text should contain only one string, either "Yes" or "No". The text should not contain both "Yes" and "No".

```
(^((?!.*No).*Yes.*)$)|(^((?!.*Yes).*No.*)$)
```

Eg:

```
Yes, correct = allow this

No, Incorrect = allow this

Yes, correct- No Incorrect = Don't allow this
```

I have tried this. But this is allowing both. any help appreciated.

Comment: Why not just use `contains()` twice?

Answer (score 1):

This stupid long regex will do it for you :P

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String s = "Yes, correct- No Incorrect";
    System.out.println(s.matches("(?=.*(?<![a-zA-Z])Yes(?![a-zA-Z]))(?=.*(?<![a-zA-Z])No(?![a-zA-Z])).*"));
}
```

O/P :

```
true
```

PS: Use `?i` to make the regex case-insensitive.

The above code check for Yes and No and ensure that they are not part of a different word (like Yesterday or Nobody)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pattern:

```
^((?:(?!No).)*Yes(?:(?!No).)*|(?:(?!Yes).)*No(?:(?!Yes).)*)$
```

Like this:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexpYesNo {
    static Pattern YesOrNoRegex = Pattern.compile( "^((?:(?!No).)*Yes(?:(?!No).)*|(?:(?!Yes).)*No(?:(?!Yes).)*)$" );

    public static boolean containsYesOrNo(
        final String input
    ){
        return YesOrNoRegex.matcher( input ).matches();
    }

    public static void main( final String[] args ){
        final String[] tests = {
                "Yes, correct = allow this",
                "No, Incorrect = allow this",
                "Yes, correct- No Incorrect = Don't allow this"
        };

        for ( final String test : tests )
            System.out.println( containsYesOrNo( test ) );
    }
}
```

However, a simpler way to do it is not to use a regular expression:

```
public static boolean containsYesOrNo(
    final String input
){
    return input.contains( "Yes" ) != input.contains( "No" );
}
```

Comment: Tempered greedy tokens can be used, but I'd also suggest using a DOTALL mode if the input has newline characters. The non-regex version will not account for whole words, and will return true for `Yesterday` and `Note`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The OP does not ask to find whole words but to see whether the input **contains** exactly one of two strings.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to do it with a regex, use

```
(?i)^(?!.*(?:\byes\b.*\bno\b|\bno\b.*\byes\b)).*\b(?:yes|no)\b.*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dL6oH4/1)

In Java:

```
String ptrn = "(?i)^(?!.*(?:\\byes\\b.*\\bno\\b|\\bno\\b.*\\byes\\b)).*\\b(?:yes|no)\\b.*";
```

Add a DOTALL modifier if your string contains newline symbols.

**Explanation:**

- `(?i)` -  enabling the case insensitive mode
- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*(?:\byes\b.*\bno\b|\bno\b.*\byes\b))` - a negative lookahead failing the match if there are `yes` or `no` or `no` and `yes` as whole words (due to word boundary `\b`) later in the string
- `.*` - matches zero or more characters other than a newline (without a DOTALL modifier(
- `\b(?:yes|no)\b` - either a `yes` or a `no`
- `.*` - zero or more  characters other than a newline (without a DOTALL modifier)